# Access contacts filters

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

The contacts on the android phone come with settings like "Filter Contacts" that lets the user set things like "Show only contacts that have phone numbers" and "Only show contacts that are online", and which sets of contacts to display (eg, phone only, phone and google etc.).

When doing this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

is there any way to get those filters applied to the contacts list?  By default it seems to return everything.  If you can't, is there some way to access those settings to see what they are, so I can build my own contacts picker list to match how the phone user has set their default?  This only needs to work for Android 2 up.

(The ideal option would be a way to invoke the contact picker that lets the user also set the filters from in there.)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you pass a URI to the intent like the one shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html), you should be able to apply your filter. So you'd do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```